# Increasing ElasticSearch Spark write rates without adverse effects on the cluster

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

My team has several Spark pipelines that write large amounts of data to Elasticsearch. In the past, these jobs crashed Elasticsearch and so now we limit the write stage to only 20 tasks in parallel. The write stage is now a major bottleneck, with it being more than half of the runtime in some pipelines.

The problem is we don't really know how to measure whether the cluster is under too much load before nodes start crashing, which is unacceptable in a production environment. How can I benchmark/test/debug the ElasticSearch Spark write rates to understand whether we can or can not increase the write rate of our jobs? I know there are many metrics in the spark cluster but I don't know what to look at, like for example what is considered acceptable write/read latency.

thanks